# freeze first column in tableview javafx

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have a tableview(javafx) where I want to freeze the first column, means if you scroll to the right side, the first column would always remain in place on screen. How can I do that? All I have just a basic code to fill data in tableview.

```
javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[] tableColumn = new javafx.scene.control.TableColumn[columnHeaderNamesArray.length];

    // add columns
    List<String> columnNames = Arrays.asList(columnHeaderNamesArray);
    for (int i = 0; i < columnNames.size(); i++)
    {
        final int finalIdx = i;
        javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<ObservableList<String>, String> column = new javafx.scene.control.TableColumn<>(columnNames.get(i));
        column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(String.valueOf(param.getValue().get(finalIdx))));
        tableColumn[finalIdx] = column;
    }

    mTableFxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    add(mTableFxPanel);
    mTableFxPanel.setVisible(true);
    tableView = new TableView<ObservableList<Object>>();

    tableView.setEditable(true);
    for (int i = 0; i < dataMatrix.length; i++)
        tableView.getItems().add(FXCollections.observableArrayList(Arrays.asList(dataMatrix[i])));

    tableView.getColumns().addAll(tableColumn);
    tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(tableView);
```

Comment: There's no API for this at the moment. It's on the wish-list for JavaFX 10. You would basically have to write your own table view skin, which is a huge undertaking.

Comment: do you know if there is any other alternative, other than Jtable

Comment: Hmm instead of reinventing the wheel by making your own table view skin. what about having two TableView next to each other? Of course you must make some bindings on data selection to make it fill like a single unit but still i believe it will look ok.

Comment: @JKostikiadis That gets really difficult too. You would want to hide the vertical scroll bar in one of the tables (which is difficult enough), ensure the headers and all the rows were the same height, and synchronize the scrolling. All that is probably as difficult as writing a new skin.

Comment: @James_D Indeed, i forgot about the vertical and horizontal bars.. ensuring the headers and all the rows were the same height is the main problem i guess, synchronization and selection in my opinion are easy to implement but still you are right the overall idea is kind of messy.. + you will have to change some css to remove the blue selection background of  the tables to match each other etc..

Comment: controlsfx might support it (didnt check, though)

Comment: @kleopatra Indeed, [`SpreadsheetView`](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/spreadsheet/SpreadsheetView.html) supports "fixed" columns (and rows).

Comment: @James_D that's bad if it's only SpreadsheetView, as it didn't make it into controlsfx 9 (basically because it's not possible to install a custom virtualFlow if I remember correctly - <rant> so they have that complex project with all the requirements of a real-world context and still couldn't move all important api into public scope < / rant>)

Comment: Spreadsheetview does support the "fixed" column option, but apparently it doesnt support other stuff which I need, like multiple header and vertical text of the column header( when its too long)

Comment: could be one of the oldest issues: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091156 - filed in Feb 2012 with a fix target of tbd-major ;)

Comment: There's no way to do this with the javafx TableView, here's a useful implementation with a JTable though, which you could put in a SwingNode if you want to go that way. https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/fixed-column-table/

Comment: I am using the above mentioned implementation in JTable. But I was planning to move to tableView and wondering if it has the same functionality

Comment: having success with a solution posted here: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/love-javafx-missing-frozen-column-table-grid-worries-here-biswa-das/.

Comment: Add in the answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Code worked with javafx 11

```
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.AccessibleAttribute;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.layout.Region;

public class LockedTableCell<T, S> extends TableCell<T, S> {
        
    {

        Platform.runLater(() -> {

            try {
                ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) getTableView()
                            .queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR);
                // set fx:id of TableColumn and get region of column header by #id
                Region headerNode = (Region) getTableView().lookup("#" + getTableColumn().getId());
                scrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((ob, o, n) -> {
                    double doubleValue = n.doubleValue();
                    
                    // move header and cell with translateX & bring it front
                    headerNode.setTranslateX(doubleValue);
                    headerNode.toFront();

                    this.setTranslateX(doubleValue);
                    this.toFront();

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
        });

    }

}
```

Using it:

```
tableColumnInstance.setCellFactory(param -> new LockedTableCell<>() {...});
```